# PHP Redirect - Hide referrer

Tags: php, redirect, referrer

On my website I want to be able to use a different referrer in order to not reveal where my traffic is coming from.

Here is an example:

```
Site 1 - www.examplesite1.com (traffic source)
Site 2 - www.examplesite2.com (site to redirect through)
Site 3 - www.partnerssite.com (where i want to push traffic from examplesite1.com)
```

So what I thought was:

On Site 1 I would link like this:
`www.examplesite2.com?p=9982` (unique id)

Then in the `index.php` file on `examplesite2.com` I will use a little script to check if `$_GET['p']` equals 9982, if it equals I will redirect to `examplesite2.com/out.php` by using `header("location:");` and then again on `out.php` I will redirect with `header("Location: www.partnerssite.com");`

My question: is there any way at all for `partnersite.com` to see that the click actually came from `examplesite1.com`?

Please excuse me if this seems messy :)

All help and tips are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless people at partnersite.com have access to examplesite2.com's server there is no way they know the traffic is coming from www.examplesite1.com.